# How can I return a count of how many orders fall within incremental ranges?

Tags: sql

I have columns called order_id and purchase_amount, and I need to write a query to count how many orders fall within each incremental range of $100, along with the values of the range. For example, it has to return something like 12 orders are between $0-100, 9 orders are between $101-200 and continuing on that way, increasing by $100 each time, like below. And I'm stumped how to begin.

> Count | Range
>
> 12    | $0-100
>
> 9 | $101-200

Answer (score 0):

Look at using SQL function SUM combined with CASE to create a condition.

```
Select SUM(CASE WHEN OrderValue >= 0 AND OrderValue < 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count FROM Table;
```

That should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any source table data sample so I did use the standard table Orders from TPCH to build the following:

```
select
    case
        when o_totalprice < 1000 then '1k-'
        when o_totalprice >= 1000 and o_totalprice < 5000 then '1k-5k'
        when o_totalprice >= 5000 and o_totalprice < 10000 then '5k-10'
        when o_totalprice >= 10000 and o_totalprice < 20000 then '10k-20k'
        when o_totalprice >= 20000 and o_totalprice < 50000 then '20k-50k'
        else '50k+'
    end as 'Range',
    count(*) as 'Range-Count'
from
    orders
group by 1
;
```

Hope this answer your question...